# Couldn't nock a function call

Tags: node.js, http, mocking

I had a problem when wanting to unit test a function that launch a http request and gets data. The request is intercepted but the function does not receive what I defined in the .reply() clause of the nock function. I have been struggling for hours without any clue of where the problem is !!!

This is my function:

```
import request from 'request';
import { pick, map } from 'lodash';
import { logger, getEnv } from './utils';


export default function getStoresFromProductDB() {
  const dataToPick = [
    'iccli',
    'store_name',
  ];
  const host = 'http://localhost:4001';
  const url = `${host}/store`;
  logger.info(`Getting stores from product DB at URL ${url}`);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        const { data } = body;
        resolve(map(data, store => pick(store, dataToPick)));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

And this my test code :

```
describe('Testing getting stores from product database', () => {
  it('should return 200 and the list of available stores from product database', async () => {
    nock('http://localhost:4001')
      .get('/store')
      .reply(200, stores);

    const data = await getStoresFromProductDB();
    console.log('​data', data);
  });
});
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: I think `nock` is very strict sometimes on what it matches on -- maybe you can try removing the `{json: true}` option from the request GET, and see if `nock` will then match on the request? If that works, then you might have to dig through the [nock documentation](https://github.com/node-nock/nock#specifying-request-body) and figure out how to match on the exact request, including body...

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I tried removing the { json: true } but still the same problem. The thing is that it does not show an error that says the request doesn't match, simply the function doesn't return anything which is weird because in the project I had other requests, basically PostgreSQL requests and all works fine with the same nock.

Answer (score 1):

oh man, I solved the problem, it was about the data format that is replied by nock. Because the getStoresFromProductDB function was expecting an object wich has a data array inside it which hold the data I want to fetch, so it is an array inside of an object, and I was replying directly an array. That was stupid.

So the test code must be like this :

```
describe('Testing getting stores from product database', () => {
  it('should return 200 and the list of available stores from product database', async () => {
    nock('http://localhost:4001')
      .get('/store')
      .reply(200, { data: stores });

    const data = await getStoresFromProductDB();
    console.log('​data', data);
  });
});
```